# Excel 2013 VBA Vlookup-Function Error

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I wrote a program, which creates a resource-Overview. At a point in the program i want to set a vlookup-function via VBA. If I set the vlookup-function manually in the sheet (write the formula into the cell)(`=SVERWEIS(B2;'MS Project'!A:H;2;FALSCH)`)("SVERWEIS" is the german word for "VLOOKUP", "FALSCH" is the german word for "FALSE") it works fine, but if I'm use the following line of code to insert this Formula automatically into the cell, it does not.

```
rngTarget.Cells(i, col + 1).value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngTarget.Range("B" & i), _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MS Project").Range("A1:H2000"), 2, 0)
```

"rngTarget" represents the usedRange of the activeSheet.

"i" represents the current row I'm working with.

The Image below shows the runtime-error (1004) I get while executing my program.

[image]

It says, that the Vlookup-Property of the WorksheetFunction-Object could not be assigned.

Edit: before this line gets executed, I check if the searched object exist in "Ms Project". Only if it does exist, it will set the vlookup-function.

**SOLUTION:** I figured out the problem, I changed:

```
rngTarget.Cells(i, col + 1).value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngTarget.Range("B" & i), _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MS Project").Range("A1:H2000"), 2, 0)
```

to:

```
rngTarget.Cells(i, col + 1).value = Application.VLookup(rngTarget.Range("B" & i).value, _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MS Project").Range("A1:H2000"), 2, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Lookup_value argument you are referencing the whole object `rngTarget.Range("B" & i)`, try adding `.Value2` to return only the value for this range.

i.e.

```
rngTarget.Cells(i, col + 1).value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngTarget.Range("B" & i).Value2, _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MS Project").Range("A1:H2000"), 2, 0)
```

Comment: I also tried that before, it changes nothing. But I will let it be rngTarget.Range("B" & i).Value.

Comment: @flohdieter please see slight amendment, try using `.Value2`

Comment: ah okay, tried it, still the same situation. Thank you for your help, i solved the problem, edited my question!